# Embedding of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ into $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

It seems natural that $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ should embed into $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is bounded (possibly with some further regularity conditions on $\Omega$).

Indeed, this is covered by a result stated without citation on the [Sobolev space Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_embeddings).

However, in both the Maz'ya book, and the Adams & Fournier one, the big Sobolev Embedding theorem statements all seem to restrict to $p<\infty$.

Is there an embedding of $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ into $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ under some assumptions on $\Omega$? Can you provide a reference for this? (Maybe it's just too obvious to warrant stating?)

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded, the embedding that you want is a consequence of Hölder's inequality applied to the function and it's derivatives; I'm not sure I've ever seen it written down explicitly somewhere though.